# Get the sum of values at the end of a day/month/week

Tags: sql, postgresql

I store the balance of different user wallets hourly on a database:

```
Table: snapshots

id      wall_id   balance          created_at
--------------------------------------------------
...

1300    30        1461.18721408    2019-07-05 18:00:05
1301    30        2922.37442816    2019-07-05 19:00:05
1302    30        228.31050220     2019-07-05 20:00:05
1303    30        2283.10502200    2019-07-05 21:00:05
1304    30        285.38812775     2019-07-05 22:00:05
1305    30        57.07762555      2019-07-05 23:00:05 <--
1306    25        2511.41552420    2019-07-05 18:00:05
1307    25        251.14155242     2019-07-05 19:00:05
1308    25        21735.61642968   2019-07-05 20:00:05
1309    25        22523.28766227   2019-07-05 21:00:05
1310    25        79.90867577      2019-07-05 22:00:05
1311    25        285.38812775     2019-07-05 23:00:05 <--
1312    100       2511.41552420    2019-07-05 18:00:05
1313    100       251.14155242     2019-07-05 19:00:05
1314    100       21735.61642968   2019-07-05 20:00:05
1315    100       22523.28766227   2019-07-05 21:00:05
1316    100       79.90867577      2019-07-05 22:00:05
1317    100       285.38812775     2019-07-05 23:00:05
1318    30        1461.18721408    2019-07-06 18:00:05
1319    30        2922.37442816    2019-07-06 19:00:05
1320    30        228.31050220     2019-07-06 20:00:05
1321    30        2283.10502200    2019-07-06 21:00:05
1322    30        285.38812775     2019-07-06 22:00:05
1323    30        79.90867577      2019-07-06 23:00:05 <--
1324    25        2511.41552420    2019-07-06 18:00:05
1325    25        251.14155242     2019-07-06 19:00:05
1326    25        21735.61642968   2019-07-06 20:00:05
1327    25        22523.28766227   2019-07-06 21:00:05
1328    25        79.90867577      2019-07-06 22:00:05
1329    25        21735.61642968   2019-07-06 23:00:05 <--
1330    100       2511.41552420    2019-07-06 18:00:05
1331    100       251.14155242     2019-07-06 19:00:05
1332    100       21735.61642968   2019-07-06 20:00:05
1333    100       22523.28766227   2019-07-06 21:00:05
1334    100       79.90867577      2019-07-06 22:00:05
1335    100       285.38812775     2019-07-06 23:00:05

...
```

Now I want to get the SUM of the last snapshots made on every day where wall.id = 30 && 25.

To understand the algorithm I marked the values that should be added.

F.e.:

```
Example result for wall_id 30 & 25 on EOD

day                           sumEOD 
--------------------------------------------------
2019-07-05 00:00:00           ‭342.4657533‬
2019-07-06 00:00:00           21815.52510545
```

Also it should be possible to modify it and get the SUM of the last snapshots made on every week where wall.id = 30 && 25.

What is the easiest way to achive this? I'm running postgresql.

Comment: Unrelated, but: the column names are only placeholder - the correct name is ``created_at``

Comment: Please explain your algorithm a little bit detailed. What is the "last". What do you mean with "day/week/month". All of them separately. Or the last day of month or what? It is not clear to me how you get "3150" for "2019-07-05"

Comment: I added more structured data to the question and made the question more clear - thanks for mentioning!

Comment: 21735 is wrong, isn't it? Because imho it has to be: 21735 + 79

Comment: right, corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the last snapshots made on every day with `group by wall_id, date(created_at)` and then join to the table and get the sum by day:

```
select 
  date(s.created_at) "day",
  sum(s.balance) sumEOD
from snapshots s inner join (
  select wall_id, max(created_at) maxdate
  from snapshots
  where wall_id in ('25', '30')
  group by wall_id, date(created_at)
) g on g.wall_id = s.wall_id and g.maxdate = s.created_at  
group by "day"
order by "day"
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7P4K1XDFgLD5S8grS2s93t/3).
Results:

```
| day                      | sumeod         |
| ------------------------ | -------------- |
| 2019-07-05T00:00:00.000Z | 342.4657533    |
| 2019-07-06T00:00:00.000Z | 21815.52510545 |
```

If you want to get the sums per week you can change:

```
group by wall_id, date(created_at)
```

to:

```
group by wall_id, date_trunc('week', created_at)
```

Comment: Works awesome, thank you!
Other answer works also, but this matches more my overall style

Answer (score 1):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=882fec6cbf08e0f60cb3090076b7960a)

```
SELECT 
    created_date,
    SUM(balance) AS sum_balance
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (1, 2)
        wall_id,
        created_at::date AS created_date,
        balance
    FROM
        snapshots
    WHERE wall_id IN (25, 30)
    ORDER BY 1, 2, created_at DESC
) s
GROUP BY created_date
```

`DISTINCT ON` gives you the first record of an ordered group. In this case the groups are `(wall_id, created_at::date)`. `created_at::date` gives the part of the timestamp. The order of course is by the group and within it, the records are ordered by their timestamp `DESC`, which orders the most recent record per day to the top of the group. This one is taken by `DISTINCT ON`.

Afterwards you can simply group your result.

Comment: Works awesome, thank you - only marked this not as accepted answer because the other one matches more my style